# What is the time complexity of the below code in python?

Tags: python

Below is a code to remove the recurrent alphabets from a string in python. I would like to know the time complexity of this code. More specifically time complexity of line `if string_1[i] not in char_found:`. Searching in a list.

Also if possible can this be explained using space allocated by a list.

```
def remove_recorring_char(string_1):
    result = ""
    char_found = []
    for i in range(0,len(string_1)):
        if string_1[i] not in char_found:
            char_found.append(string_1[i])
            result = result+string_1[i]
    return result

if __name__== "__main__":
    print(remove_recorring_char("aabbbcc"))
    print(remove_recorring_char("chdsgdsgggsggsjddaaxcvcj"))
```

Comment: Is the time complexity of if statement is O(n)? I'm looking for a reasoning here.

Comment: Membership tests on lists are O(N) on the size of the list (a linear search is used). You should use a `set` object, which has constant-time membership testing, and would be the typical container used in this situation.

Comment: It's worth looking at the [Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) in the `itertools` docs. The `unique_everseen` function is a slightly more general version of what you're doing (it works on any iterable, not just strings, and can take an optional `key` function that works the same way as in `sort` or `max`), and also a good demonstration of how to do this efficiently.

Comment: To add to what @juanpa.arrivillaga says, set isn't just more efficient, it's also probably clearer. When you use a set, it means you don't care about order, don't need duplicate values, and aren't doing anything but membership tests (and related things like intersection—all values in both set A and set B—or difference—all values in set A but not set B), because that's what sets do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if string_1[i] not in char_found:
```

This line does two things:

First, it accesses `string_1[i]`. That takes constant time, because strings are basically just arrays of characters.

Then it searches in a list `char_found`, comparing that character `string_1[i]` to each element until one matches. That takes (worst-case) linear time in the length of `char_found`. And, since `char_found` could (worst-case) be all of the characters in `string_1[:i]`, that's linear in the length of `string_1`.

So, this line is `O(N)`.

And of course this line is inside an outer loop that's even more obviously `O(N)`: `for i in range(0,len(string_1)):`. So, that combination of the two is `O(N**2)`.

Even if you fix that `in` test to be constant time, you also do `result = result+string_1[i]` inside the loop. String concatenation is worst-case linear in the length of the string. Recent versions of CPython and PyPy have some optimizations so it's sometimes amortized constant time, like appending to a list, but Python the language doesn't guarantee those optimizations. And `result` is, worst-case, also as long as `string_1`. So, the whole thing is still `O(N**2)`, unless your interpreter is extra nice.

---

You could reduce the whole thing to `O(N)` by making two small changes.

First, use a `set` rather than a `list` for `char_found`. Searching a set, and adding to it, are both amortized constant-time operations.

Second, use a `list` rather than a `str` for `result`, then do `result = ''.join(result)` at the end. Appending to a list is amortized constant-time. Converting a list back to a string is of course linear time, but you're not doing it inside your loops, so that's fine.

Comment: Thank you. Was looking for this!

Comment: Cheat for Python 3.6 or better: `print(''.join(dict.fromkeys('chdsgdsgggsggsjddaaxcvcj')))` prints `chdsgjaxv`. (Yes I know dictionary order isn't guaranteed in the docs until 3.7.)  Same time complexity as using a set.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski `print(''.join(toolz.unique('chdsgdsgggsggsjddaaxcvcj')))` is even shorter, and I think more obvious in meaning, and it works back to 2.6/3.2. It does require a third-party library. But you can just copy `unique_everseen` out of the `itertools` recipes to get the same effect.

Comment: Shorter if you're not counting imports, but definitely way clearer. There's no way I would put the `dict.fromkeys` version in my code without a short comment so my point about the import is moot.